# Solutions to a DE: Vector space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

For every homogeneous DE, are it's solutions always a vector space, considering it will always contains the zero vector and is closed under +, x?
Are there any homogeneous DE's whos solutions are not a vector space?

Also are all non-homogeneous DE solutions never a vector space? What if a DE equals a trig function, does it contain the zero vector now and can be called a vector space?

Comment: This may be more advanced than you need (or it may even conflict with definitions given in class) but if you allow homogeneous DEs which are nonlinear— there are such things, and their solutions need not form a vector space. But you are right that linear homogeneous DEs have solution spaces which are vector spaces, for the reason you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $y\equiv 0 $ will never be a solution to a non-homogeneous DE, so already we lose any hope of having a vector space.  Moreover, if I have a non-homogeneous DE: $\mathcal{L} y=  g$ then the only way for the space of solutions to be closed under linear operations is if $g=0$.  Indeed, note that if $y_1,y_2$ are solutions to $\mathcal{L} y = g$, and I want $y_1-y_2$ to be a solution as well, then

$$g=\mathcal{L}(y_1-y_2) = \mathcal{L}y_1 - \mathcal{L}{y_2} = g-g =0.$$